# Installing Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to install wireshark with help from [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YYEIV35IlE)

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark libcap2-bin
sudo groupadd wireshark
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark debbase
```

But I faced a problem when I ran the command `sudo usermod -a -G wireshark debbase`. It gives the error:

```
user 'debbase' does not exist
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this example, `debbase` is the provided username. Replace it with your username. This would be the one you entered when you installed and set up Ubuntu.

You can also find your username by entering a shell and typing:

```
whoami
```

What that command does is adds the user `debbase` to the group `wireshark`

Comment: ohhh....I forgot...:-( username is lara. But It is not working....!!!

Comment: What does it say now?

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept my answer as the working solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer to help people in the future.

Answer (score 2):

**debbase** is the username of the individual in the tutorial.

You need to replace "debbase" with your **local username**.

If you aren't sure, you can type `whoami` in your terminal to get this information.